# How to convert minutes and seconds of audio/video to currentTime in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the string of video time is "02:30" and video.duration of video is 239. Now, how to convert "02:30" to currentTime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A one line solution**

If you want a simple one line solution you could use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). Note that split returns a `string[2]`, but we convert these to numbers by applying math operators, for example +mm is shorthand for Number(mm). Also see MDN [JavaScript arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#examples)

```
let toMinutes = hhmm => hhmm.split(":").reduce((hh, mm) => +mm + 60 * hh );
```

**Run the code snippet to view test output**

```js
let toMinutes = hhmm => hhmm.split(":").reduce((hh, mm) => +mm + 60 * hh );

// TEST

["00:30", "1:00", "01:15", "1:30", "01:45", "2:00", "2:15", "2:30", "2:45", "3:00", "24:00" ].forEach(t => {

  console.log(`${t} = ${toMinutes(t)} minutes`)
  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `split(":")` can solve that, i hope below will help you:

```js
function convert(str){
  let a = str.split(':')
  return Number(a[0]) * 60 + Number(a[1])
}
const currentTime = convert('02:30')
console.log("currentTime is", currentTime)
```